# I have the following English sentence that I need to convert into a sentence of predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> If some person is tall, then every person is tall.

Is this written as

$$\exists x(P(x) \land T(x)) \to \forall x(P(x) \to T(x))$$

or

$$\exists x(P(x) \land T(x)) \to \forall y(P(y) \to T(y))$$

or something completely different?

Comment: The first looks good to me. The second needs some parentheses to even make it a sentence.

Comment: MSE is a constant source of inspiration for me. I hadn't thought about your second alternative. Updated my blog posting on "The Drinkers' Paradox." See: https://dcproof.wordpress (see highlighted text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"There exists a person who, if he is is tall, then every person is tall."

(*) $\exists x \in P \ (T(x) \implies \forall x \in P, \ T(x))$

Interestingly, this statement is *true*. There is some person in the world such that if that person is tall, then everyone is tall. How can this seemingly absurd statement be true?

Well, suppose that there exists some person $x$ who is not tall. Then $T(x)$ is false, making the implication $T(x) \implies \forall x \in P, \ T(x))$ true.

But suppose every person is tall. Then the consequent of (*), $\forall x \in P, \ T(x))$, is true; making the implication true.

This story is known as the [Drinker's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox). In every (nonempty) bar, there's someone such that if he is drinking, then everyone is drinking. (And of course an empty bar would go out of business so we need not consider that case :-))

Comment: Excellent! Didn't make the connection between my example and the drinker's paradox somehow

Comment: @rmw If you like my answer please consider upvoting. If it fully resolves your question to your satisfaction, please consider *accepting* it.

Comment: would up vote it but apparently don't have the necessary level of reputation

Comment: @rwm Oh I see. I'm just getting the hang of this system myself. Thanks for the checkmark.

Comment: That should be: $\exists x \in P \ (T(x) \implies \forall y \in P, \ T(y))$ Then it would be like the Drinkers Paradox. See Grahams answer.

Answer (score 2):

> If some person is tall, then every person is tall.

Do you mean, "If there is some person who is tall, then every person is tall"?

$$\tag{1} \Big(\exists x \big(P(x)\wedge T(x)\big)\Big) \to \Big(\forall y \big(P(y)\to T(y)\big)\Big)\\ \equiv \\
\Big(\exists x \in P:T(x)\Big) \to \Big(\forall y\in P: T(y)\Big)$$

Or do you mean "There is some person who, if they are tall then every person is tall."  (vis the 'Drinker's Paradox')

$$\tag{2} \exists x \Big(P(x)\wedge \big(T(x) \to \forall y \big(P(y)\to T(y)\big)\big)\Big)
\\ \equiv \\
\exists x\in P:\Big(T(x) \to \big(\forall y\in P:T(y)\big)\Big)
$$

The scope brackets are important here.   (1) and (2) are quite different statements.

Comment: Yes. If there exists at least one person, then the latter must be true. If there are at least two people, that former is not true in general.

Comment: To show that the first alternative is not true in general, consider the possibility that we have two people, one of which is tall and the other not tall: $$  P(a)\land P(b)\land  T(a)\land \neg T(b)$$


Then we can easily prove that $$\neg\exists x(P(x) \land T(x)) \to \forall x(P(x) \to T(x))$$

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

Denote the set of people by $X$ and the statement "$x$ is tall" by $T(x)$. Then:

$$\exists x\in X : T(x)\implies T(y)\:\forall y\in X$$

Comment: Interesting to see a different approach thanks